# Shopping cart: Cookies only holding 2 - 5 items

Tags: javascript, variables, cookies, session-cookies, shopping-cart

### This is likely an easy fix (easy +200 reputation), for someone who has javascript skills.

### Demo of problem: http://shoppingcart-bthub.blogspot.com/ Just add all the items to the cart and click refresh to see the problem with the cookies.

Everything works correctly, except the part of the code that handles cookies for the items that get added to the shopping cart. For some reason, it only holds 2 -5 items, depending on the broswer:

Google Chrome - only holds 2 items (all other items in shopping cart disappear after page reload)

Firefox - 4 items total

Safari - 4

Internet Exploer - 5

The javascript in the demo:
http://shopppingcart.googlecode.com/files/simplecart.js

The part of the javascript link above that is coded to handle cookies:

```
    /*** data storage and retrival ****/ 
/* load cart from cookie */ 
me.load = function () {
var me = this;
 /* initialize variables and items array */
me.items = {};
me.total = 0.00;
me.quantity = 0;

 /* retrieve item data from cookie */
if( readCookie('simpleCart') ){
var data = unescape(readCookie('simpleCart')).split('++');
for(var x=0, xlen=data.length;x<xlen;x++){
var info = data[x].split('||');
var newItem = new CartItem();   
if( newItem.parseValuesFromArray( info ) ){
newItem.checkQuantityAndPrice();

/* store the new item in the cart */
 me.items[newItem.id] = newItem;
 }
 }
 }
 me.isLoaded = true;
};

/* save cart to cookie */
me.save = function () {
var dataString = "";
for( var item in this.items ){
dataString = dataString + "++" + this.items[item].print();
}
createCookie('simpleCart', dataString.substring( 2 ), 30 );
};
```

### To test the full live code:

For the complete live template with all the codes, open a free blog at blogger.com and download the XML template here to upload into blogger: http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/05/shopping-cart-blogger-template/ The free download is in the left-hand sidebar. Also follow the intructions on that page to get it woking in blogger.com

Comment: Hi Loop, I have just tested the simplecart.js (the first one) both in IE10 and Chrome. Seems I cannot reproduce your bug. I created 10 items with looong names, and added 10 units of each item to cart. My simplecart cookie is 1136 bytes length. I suggest 2 things: 1. Validate you have no cookie limitations/permission issues, 2. share your html/js, maybe the bug is in your code.

Comment: A demo of the shopping cart that I am using can be found here: http://shoppingcart-bthub.blogspot.in/ Everything on the page .js and HTML wise is the exact same as on my site. The bug is the same on this site too. Just add all the items and click refresh and you will see the bug.

Comment: I would love to post all the HTML with it in my post but because it is in the blogger.com platform, it's extremely huge. Hopefully the view source and inspect elments of that demo site will help narrow down the bug that I am getting. Anything else you need, please let me know.

Comment: I am quite curious how you tested the js file without knowing the HTML that creates the cart and works together with the js? I was hoping someone with js skills could simply look at the tiny part of the js (the first code in my post) that handles cookies & see why it's only holding a limited amount. I dont see how this bug could be related to anything else other than how the js handles cookies? Hence the bug happens after refresh of the broswer. Anyhow, thank you for trying. I will post the HTML that creates the cart above (even though its visible on the demo site, it will make it easier).

Comment: I created a simple html page that works with simplecart. I suggested you to share html+js because you have mentioned some customization you have there, not because I can't write a sample by myself :)

Comment: If you can identify the problem on the demo page http://shoppingcart-bthub.blogspot.in/, I can fix the problem on my custom site, since the base code is exactly the same.

Comment: If you like some live code to work with and test, the exact base codes on the demo, I suggest open a free blog at blogger.com and download the template here to upload into blogger: http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/05/shopping-cart-blogger-template/ The free download is in the left-hand sidebar.

Comment: @Enzino, just tried it. No, still only holds the same amount of items in cookies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is related to the 4K cookie size limit.
Your `shopppingcart` code is trying to store all the items data in a `simpleCart` cookie, but when such data gets bigger than 4K the items are not stored into the cookie, even if they're showed in the cart, therefore when the page is reloaded those items disappear.
Consider for example the site http://shoppingcart-bthub.blogspot.in/, and specifically the HTML markup for the "Sony VAIO laptop" item:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 660px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="item_thumb" id="thumb" width="45%"><img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LcQD--Bb_YE/TeDI44AmUsI/AAAAAAAACBw/K4IJZE2CpMY/s1600/sony+vaio.JPG"></th>
            <td>
                <input class="item_add" type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="s1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Item Name</b></th>
            <td class="item_name">Sony VPCEE42FX 15.5" 2.30GHz 500GB VAIO Laptop</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Price</b></th>
            <td class="item_price">$610.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Description</b></th>
            <td class="item_Description">
            The VPCEE42FX is big enough to be useful, but small 
            enough to be portable. With 500GB of hard drive space, youll have to work hard 
            to fill up the memory. The 15.5 HD resolution screen and AMD Mobility Radeon HD 
            graphics card ensure that youll see crisp, fast action, even when youre watching 
            DVDs on the DVD drive. And at under six pounds, the laptop is easy to pack up 
            and haul with you.
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Available Stock</b></th>
            <td>2 more available</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When this product is added to the cart, the `simpleCart` cookie will contain the following string:

> id=c10||thumb=%3Cimg%20border%3D%220%22%20src%3D%22http%3A//3.bp.blogspot.com/-LcQD--Bb_YE/TeDI44AmUsI/AAAAAAAACBw/K4IJZE2CpMY/s1600/sony+vaio.JPG%22%3E%0A||name=Sony%20VPCEE42FX%2015.5%22%202.30GHz%20500GB%20VAIO%20Laptop||price=610||description=The%20VPCEE42FX%20is%20big%20enough%20to%20be%20useful%2C%20but%20small%20enough%20to%20be%20%0Aportable.%20With%20500GB%20of%20hard%20drive%20space%2C%20youll%20have%20to%20work%20hard%20to%20%0Afill%20up%20the%20memory.%20The%2015.5%20HD%20resolution%20screen%20and%20AMD%20Mobility%20%0ARadeon%20HD%20graphics%20card%20ensure%20that%20youll%20see%20crisp%2C%20fast%20action%2C%20even%20%0Awhen%20youre%20watching%20DVDs%20on%20the%20DVD%20drive.%20And%20at%20under%20six%20pounds%2C%20the%20%0Alaptop%20is%20easy%20to%20pack%20up%20and%20haul%20with%20you.||quantity=1

As you can see, it seems that all the `<td>` elements with a class name starting with `item_` are stored in the cookie.
Chrome Developer's Tools shows a size of 828 bytes for this cookie.
Therefore the number of the items that can be added to the cart is variable and depends by the length of each item data (name, description, etc.).
So, what can you do to avoid this problem?

1. Reduce the item HTML markup to the minimum, for example by removing the `item_thumb` and  `item_Description` elements.
2. Modify the `addToCart` method in the `simplecart.js` code to reduce the lenght of the cookie by storing less information (see below for details).
3. Modify the `createCookie`, `readCookie` and `eraseCookie` functions in the `simplecart.js` code to use [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) instead of a cookie to store item data (have a look at [this page](https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/blob/master/simpleCart.js) for a code sample, or below for another example).

For example, to avoid the storing of the "thumb" and "Description" item fields in the cookie, you could modify the `addToCart` method as follows:

```
ShelfItem.prototype.addToCart = function () {
  var outStrings = [],valueString;
  for( var field in this ){
    if( typeof( this[field] ) != "function" && field != "id" ){
      valueString = "";

      //console.log(field);
      switch(field){
        case "price":
          if( this[field].value ){
            valueString = this[field].value;
          } else if( this[field].innerHTML ) {
            valueString = this[field].innerHTML;
          }
          /* remove all characters from price except digits and a period */
          valueString = valueString.replace( /[^(\d|\.)]*/gi , "" );
          valueString = valueString.replace( /,*/ , "" );
          break;
        case "image":
          valueString = this[field].src;
          break;
        case "thumb":
        case "Description":
        case "description":
          /* don't store "thumb" and "description" in the cookie */
          break;
        default:
          if( this[field].value ){
            valueString = this[field].value;
          } else if( this[field].innerHTML ) {
            valueString = this[field].innerHTML;
          } else if( this[field].src ){
            valueString = this[field].src;
          } else {
            valueString = this[field];
          }
          break;
      }
      outStrings.push( field + "=" + valueString );
    }
  }
}
```

A much better approach would be to use `localStorage` if the browser supports it, otherwise use cookies as a fallback:

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (supports_html5_storage()) {
    if (value == '') {
      eraseCookie(name);
    } else {
      window.localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
  } else {
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }
}

function readCookie(name) {
  if (supports_html5_storage()) {
    return window.localStorage.getItem(name);
  } else {
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
  }
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  if (supports_html5_storage()) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(name);
  } else {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
  }
}
```

When using `localStorage` we can also store the `thumb` and `description` fields without problems (since we have 5 Mb of space), therefore we can further modify the `ShelfItem.prototype.addToCart` function this way:

```
  ...
  case "thumb":
  case "Description":
  case "description":
    if (!supports_html5_storage()) break;
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This information was extremely helpful. I removed all the descriptions from every post using a simple CSS code in the template and it worked! Could you perhaps recode it to where it shows everything as it is minus the description from every cookie? Obviously I don't need the description to be in the cookie. But I want the thumb, by the time it gets transfered to the cookie, it's a tiny thumb, so I want that to stay. If you do this for me and it works, I will award you the +200.

Comment: I am just taking a guess here because I don't know js code, but if I remove: case "image":
          valueString = this[field].src;
          break;
        case "thumb":
 from your above code, it will still show the image thumb and still be a valid working code, is this right?

Comment: I added an upvote to your answer @Enzino because of the very informed answer. I like to learn and gain knowledge and this answer has helped with that and also addressed the question directly. Just need my question above answered to award you the selected answer and +200.

Comment: Sorry @Enzino the other answer by:vsenik beat you to it. He had already re=wrote the js to not add the descriptions into the cookies. I wish I could have awarded you due to this priceless information and knowledge you provided but I have to be integral, I hope you understand.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much @Enzino You are amazing! I will use this. You're so helpful and full of knowledge. I bet you could even figure out how to get the cart to checkout with BOTH Paypal and Google Wallet. That's what I am working on now. Wish I had the knowledge you do! Thank you again for spending so much time on this and providing such clear and full answers that help far beyond the question! Also wish I could give you something in return. You're so giving, such an extremely  rare caliber of a person.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are catching black cat in a dark room and cat isn't there.

So what I've done:

1. Get http://shopppingcart.googlecode.com/files/simplecart.js
2. Get html from http://wojodesign.com/simpleCart/
3. Replace simplecart.js with yours.

What I've found:

1. When you open html page from filesystem then you have what you have
2. If you put it on a server (in my case local instance of apache) then everything works fine

### 2 Episode.

You trying to put to much information in cookie.
Simple way modify print function like this

```
CartItem.prototype.print = function () {
    var returnString = '';
    for( var field in this ) {
      if( typeof( this[field] ) != "function" && field !="description") {
        returnString+= escape(field) + "=" + escape(this[field]) + "||";
      }
    }
    return returnString.substring(0,returnString.length-2);
  };
```

Do you really need all item fields in cookie?

Comment: Actually, this js was coded and created for the Blogger.com platform. I have a blogger template in which this js is working perfectly except the cookies only hold 2-5 items in the cart. This has always been the case, hence on their demo site: http://shoppingcart-bthub.blogspot.in/ same problem. The cart is working minus this one problem which the creators didn't fix (in this version). I need this version fixed because everything around my cart site is extremely customized, I would lose a months worth of work. It doesn't even look like the same demo but all the base codes are the same.

Comment: Just in case I wasn't clear enough. The shopping cart on this page: http://wojodesign.com/simpleCart/ is a completely different shopping cart than on this page (just built by the same team): http://shoppingcart-bthub.blogspot.in/  The js on the second page is the one I am using ( http://shopppingcart.googlecode.com/files/simplecart.js ) which is a different version than on the first page. I cant use the js on the first because of the extreme customizations preformed over the last month.

Comment: Ok. I have some workaround. Try to modify print function. Original one put to much information.

Comment: I would like all items fields in the cookie except the description, is that possible?

Comment: Yes. I add print function to answer.